# Creating Custom Image Picker Controls- applying cropping

Tags: ios

I am designing a custom image picker, for that I am using view controllers, I have successfully used camera to take picture and proceed it to PreviewControllerVC, now I want to apply cropping on that screen.

any suggest.

Comment: Check : https://github.com/dzenbot/DZNPhotoPickerController

Comment: link shows a complete photo picker library, I need something that can just crop the image as per user requirements so that I can use resulted image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer myself, **HIPImageCropperView** is the library i used for it.
It's best for this purpose.